# Get Latest Rows by Date and Name

Tags: r, function, subset

I have a DataFrame named "iceland" with 3 relevant columns: "date, name, points", which is already sorted ascending after date:

p.E.:

```
#  date        name    points
1. 2.5.2006    Bob     3
2. 5.7.2006    Lara    12
3. 7.9.2006    Hans    22
4. 12.10.2006  Bob     1
5. 17.11.2006  Hans    11
6. 1.12.2006   Bob     45
7. 22.12.2006  Steven  96
```

..and I want to get a new DataFrame with the latest row of each name according to date.

..or even better just the name and points.

p.E.:

```
#  date        name    points
2. 5.7.2006    Lara    12
5. 17.11.2006  Hans    11
6. 1.12.2006   Bob     45
7. 22.12.2006  Steven  96

or 

name    points
Lara    12
Hans    11
Bob     45
Steven  96
```

I tried answers from this: [How to get last data for each id/date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729842/how-to-get-last-data-for-each-id-date)

but seem to mess something up, as I am not that familiar with R.

Subsetting DataTable:

```
> dt1 <- data.table(iceland)
> dt[, .SD[.N], by=c("points","date")]
```

And get the Error:

```
Error in dt[, .SD[.N], by = c("points", "date")] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

And with a function:

```
> f <- function(id,mydf) {
+     tempdf <- mydf[mydf$points==id,]
+     return(tempdf[which.max(tempdf$date),])
+ }
> res <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(unique(iceland$date),f,mydf=iceland)))
> rownames(res) <- NULL
```

which shows nothing:

```
> res

    id date name points
1                                                                                                    
2                                                                                                    
3                                                                                                    
4                                                                                                    
5                                                                                                    
6
```

I would like an answer and maybe an explanation as to how to get to that answer - I would like to understand R a bit more.

Comment: `setDT(df)[, .SD[.N], by=name]`

Comment: @RonakShah so this works because the data is sorted after date, right? how would it look like if it was not sorted? (just sort it and then do this?) - ty for your answer

Comment: you first need to convert `date` column to actual date object, then sort it by `date` and then use the above.

Comment: As @RonakShah said, convert your `date` column, but you don't need to sort it, just filter by the maximum date:

`b <- a %>% dplyr::mutate(date2 = lubridate::date(as.POSIXct(date, format = '%d.%m.%Y'))) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(name) %>% 
  filter(date2 == max(date2)) %>% 
  select(name, points)`